# Remote application monitoring through Visual GC

Tags: monitoring, visualvm

I am trying to monitor an application available on remote machine using VisualVM & Visual GC.

I have enabled the `jmxremote` on the remote side as follows:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8888,
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

While monitoring through VisualVM, everything runs fine but VisualGC doesn't displays any stats (getting `Not Supported for this JVM` error).

While tried to monitor one local application, VisualGC runs fine...

Got success with the remote app once started `jstad` on the remote jvm.

Is this a known issue with VisualGC...?

Remote JVM - 1.5
Local JVM - 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, `jstatd` must be running on remote host, because VisualGC uses `jvmstat` and it does not use `jmx`.